# Getting ErrorException while attempting to read property "title" on array

Tags: laravel

While using this code:

```
  @if($loop->even)
    <div>{{ $key }}.{{$post->title}}</div>
    @else
    <div style="background-color: silver">{{ $key }}.{{$post->title}}</div>
    @endif


    <div>
        <form action="{{ route('posts.destroy',['post' => $post->id]) }}" method="POST" >
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            
            <input type="submit" value="Delete !" >
        </form>
     </div>
```

I am getting an error :

> ErrorException Attempt to read property "title" on array (View:
> E:\xampp\htdocs\laravelclass\resources\views\posts\partials\post.blade.php)

How to solve it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If its array then you can retrieve value as  `$post['title']`. In the case of collection, you can use `$post->title`.

Comment: I think the error is clear. you try to read `title` as an object property, but the variable `$post` is an array. This is very basic PHP and you could have found out yourself

Comment: Quick tip: use css for giving the odd titles another background color.